# Annotations to show labels on multiple points

Tags: highcharts, bubble-chart

I have a bubble chart where I need to find the no of bubbles overlapped and if the no of bubbles overlapped in a particular group is more than two, i need not show the data label for those bubbles. Instead i should display a label kind of thing over that particular group which has the text "Bubble count: #". Is it possible to achieve the same using annotations or is there any other way to place labels over a group of bubbles. Attached the sample img and fiddle for more clarification. Any timely help would be greatly appreciated.[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NmB2.png)

Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/m53tevbq/

```
$(function() {
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'bubble',
      zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      reversed: true,
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          var _dayInMillis = 1000 * 3600 * 24;
          var _backEndVal = this.value; //Value from Backend

          var _curr = new Date(); //getting the current date         
          var _currUTC = Date.UTC(_curr.getUTCFullYear(), _curr.getUTCMonth(), _curr.getUTCDate());

          var _diff = Math.floor((_currUTC - _backEndVal) / _dayInMillis);
          var _noOfYrs = Math.floor(_diff / 365);

          return _noOfYrs + ' Year';
        }
      }
    }
}
})
```

Comment: Any ideas on this please?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to **create groups of overlapped points**, **display only one data label per group** (e.g. for the first point) and **position it properly** using 
 coordinates of all points in the group (so that it's in the center of the group -
 marked as `TODO` in code).

```
    load: function() {
      var points = this.series[0].points,
        chart = this;
      points.forEach(function(p) {
        if (!p.group) {
          var overlappingBubbles = getRecursedPoints(p, chart);
          if (overlappingBubbles.length > 1) {
            overlappingBubbles.forEach(function(op, i) {
              op.group = overlappingBubbles;
              if (i > 0) {
                op.update({
                  dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                  }
                }, false);
              } else {
                op.update({
                  dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                    format: "Overlapped bubbles: " + op.group.length
                      // TODO: compute the offest for the label 
                      // based on coordinates of all points in the group
                      //x: some_value,
                      //y: some_value
                  }
                }, false);
              }
            });
          }
        }
      });
      chart.redraw();
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/sm1yh5ad/

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bubble.dataLabels
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update